# Comma delimited user input

Tags: python

I am currently working on the following project where I receive input from a user, a string and an integer separated by a comma. I then add them to a list and extract the integers using .split() and perform some math functions on them. Now I currently do not have any measures in place to prevent the user from inputting incorrect data and then it throwing an error when I get to the else block to perform the math. Is there a way I can specify parameters for the input and then print a message to notify the user they have input incorrectly?

What I have got so far:

```
name_age = []
user_input = []
name_age2 = []
ages = []

while user_input != "":
    user_input = input("Type 'Name,Age': ")
    name_age.append(user_input)
    print(name_age)


else:
    name_age.remove("")

    for item in name_age:
        name_age2.append(item.split(','))

    for pair in name_age2:
        for val in pair:
            if val.isdigit():
                ages.append(int(val))

    print(name_age2)
    print(ages)
    print("Names & Ages: ", name_age2)
    print("Total of ages: ", sum(ages))
    print("Average of ages: ", sum(ages) / len(ages))
    print("Total number of names: ", len(name_age2))
    print("End")
```

Comment: try looking up `try except` statements and use those with `if` statements

Comment: thanks, having a go at that now